Figuring out the normal map that is the "difference" between two other normal maps
I'm trying to "cancel out", as much as possible, a bit of geometry in a low poly 3D model (which is fixed and unmodifiable to me) with clever use of a normal map (my own research has indicated that you can take the "difference" between the actual geometry's normal, and the desired geometry's normal, then invert that, to achieve this effect).
If it matters, the desired geometry's normal is a flat surface entirely (i.e. I'm trying to "hide" some crevices and holes in the 3D model, making its surface appear flat), so perhaps that simplifies things a bit.
Any help would be much appreciated.
